# ReferenceError: usersWithSecrets is not defined at eval (eval at compile/

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am trying this but every time I faced this error, I am trying this but every time I faced this error,
I am trying this but every time I faced this error:

```
ReferenceError: D:\Secrets - Starting Code\views\submit.ejs:8
    6|     <h1 class="display-3">Secrets</h1>
    7| 
 >> 8|     <%usersWithSecrets.forEach(function(user){%>
    9|       <p class="secret-text"><%=user.secret%></p>
    10|       <%})%>
    11| 

usersWithSecrets is not defined
    at eval (eval at compile (D:\Secrets - Starting Code\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:673:12), <anonymous>:13:7)
```

**App.js Code:**

```
app.get("/secrets", function(req, res){
    User.find({"secret": {$ne: null}}, function(err, foundUser){
      if(err){
        console.log(err)
      } else{
        if(foundUser){
          res.render("secrets", {usersWithSecrets: foundUser});
        }
      }
    });
});
```

**submit.ejs code:**

```
<% usersWithSecrets.forEach(function(user){ %>
   <p class="secret-text"><%=user.secret%></p>
 <%})%>
```

Comment: sry but can you explain shortly in more detail what your goal is? If i understand right you want to check for something like jwt token?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. So I had created a new page where I have used the exactly same code and it had solved the problem. If I may explain bit more,
I had previously "secrets page". Then I have created a secrets2 page with exactly the same code.
When User will login first or register first they will go to "secrets page". Then if the user chooses to submit his secrets then after clicking the submit button the user will be redirected to the secrets2 page where all the secrets will be fetched from MongoDB database and will be displayed there without any issues.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).